# Laravel 8: Multiple Auth guards it still redirect me to login page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to create Multiple Authentication using **laravel guards** I create some stuff but it still redirect me to sign in page even if the **credentials** is correct??

I have attached some Codes from the laravel files that I have modified to achieve that.

**app\Models\Writer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Writer extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'writers';
    
    protected $guard = 'writer';
    
    ...
}
```

**config\auth.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'writers',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'writers',
        ],
        
        'writer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'writers',
        ],
        ...
    ],
    
    'providers' => [
        'writers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Writer::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'writers' => [
            'provider' => 'writers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        ...
    ],
    ...
];
```

**app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if ($guard == 'writer' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**routes\web.php**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Writer\WriterController;

Route::prefix('writer')->group(function () {
    Route::middleware(['auth:writer'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('dashboard', [WriterController::class, 'writerDashboard'])->name('writer.dashboard');
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove `$guard == 'writer' &&` from if statement.

Comment: but How I can check if it's **writer** when account is registered because I have anoter guard named **publisher**

Comment: This middleware is only responsible for checking whether a user is logged in or not. Checking user type must be performed on another middleware.

Comment: can you help me please with that

Comment: If a user is logged in, He/she must not be able to see login page. Apply *RedirectIfAuthenticated* only for this purpose.

Comment: I suggest you using [spatie laravel permission](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission)

Comment: I have two tables in the database one for **writers** and another for **publishers** what I want to achieve is if the visitor choose to register an account as **writer** it will display a register form with specified fields for **writers** and same thing for **publishers**. after that I want to check if the user is logged in as **writer** or **publisher** if is logged in as **writer** is will redirect him/her to specified **dashboard** made only for **writers**

Comment: It is another question, but I rather handle this using only one table for users with two roles. You can define your custom redirection logic in `redirectTo` method of LoginController. Please read the doc of spatie laravel permission.

Comment: I will do that thank you so mush

Comment: but without third party package How can I achieve that ??

Comment: @jhon-jhones You're making things more difficult and complicated for yourself. Your `writer` and `publisher` concepts are `roles` in [Role-Based Access Control](https://digitalguardian.com/blog/what-role-based-access-control-rbac-examples-benefits-and-more). I also suggest you review the Spatie permissions package recommended by @BABAKASHRAFI.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me:

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  ...$guards
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        if (Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
            return redirect('/web/dashboard');
        }
        elseif (Auth::guard('writer')->check()) {
            return redirect('/writer/dashboard');
        }

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `[null]` with your guards: `['web', 'writer']`

```
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? ['web', 'writer'] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```